# Visual Basic 2010 using .left

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i want to know if what is the thing that calculate when i call "object.LEFT" in visual basic express 2010, same thing as right bottom and .top..

thankz in advance! ^^

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: You would need to provide far more detail - what is `Object`?.  Also, how does this have anything to do with VBA?

Comment: i want to know about .Left property and what its function.

Answer (score 0):

`object.left` is a property of a control that specifies its relative distance (in pixels) from  the control's parent container.

For example: if you have `object.left` set to `50`, then it will push the control in 50 pixels from the left side of the container (i.e. a `Form` in WinForms development or `Page` in ASP.NET development).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I could be more specific if you provided more specific detail about the specific object, and what your purpose was.

In VB there are .Left, .Top, .Width and .Height properties that are usually measured in screen pixels to define the position and size of a Control (ListBox, CheckBox, TextBox, etc) on a Form. Footnote: VBForms can be set to use twips, points, centimeters and inches as their basic measurement.

In Office (Word, PowerPoint, Excel) there are controls that are similar but NOT the same exactly as those in VB UI. They can be placed on a UserForm using these same properties. To place them on a Word document however, you need the .GetPoint method that allows you to specify a .Range object on your document and this function will fill-in the placement information

myWorkingDoc.Windows.Item(1).GetPoint ScPixLeft, ScPixTop, ScPixWidth, ScPixHeight, _
      TblControl.Rows.Item(4).Cells.Item(1).Range.OMaths.Item(1).Range

The above line defines 4 Long integers: ScPixLeft, ScPixTop, ScPixWidth, ScPixHeight and a Range object in a word document, in the above case a Word Table named TblControl, the 4th row, 2nd (cell) column. WIthin a Word document window object the .GetPoint method gives one the relative placement, in pixels, within the document window. I use ScPixWidth and ScPixHeight to give me the size of the math equation (OMath object) so I can size an InlineShape to contain it.